# ASP.NET Core Build Issue within docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm trying out a sample to run an ASP .NET Core Web App with docker This builds fine outside the container and runs fine. But the same from within the container fails.

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80  -v "${pwd}:c:\app"  -w "c:\app"    microsoft/aspnetcore-build
```

(In container)

```
C:\app>dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.179.6572 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restoring packages for C:\app\app.csproj...
  Restore completed in 215.39 ms for C:\app\app.csproj.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\app\obj\app.csproj.nuget.g.props.
**C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.202\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Access to the path is denied. [C:\app\app.csproj]**
```

Build FAILED.

Comment: Please share your `Dockerfile` in the question.

Comment: Do you target linux container or windows container? It seems you did not configure the permission to access `c:\app`, if you are targeting windows container, make sure you `Docker->Settings->Shared Drives->C is checked`

Comment: @MoienTajik don't have a docker file.I just pulled  microsoft/aspnetcore-build  containter and with the code files on the host...I am trying to tun it in the container. docker run -it -p 8080:80  -v "${pwd}:c:\app"  -w "c:\app"    microsoft/aspnetcore-build

Comment: @TaoZhou  I am docker for windows and using windows container. I see the share option only if I switch to Linux container

Comment: @ChethanM My mistake, check the permission for `c:\app` folder. Can you make a test with non-C Drive?

Comment: @TaoZhou Permissions look good and I don't have option to try with non C-drive , as I'm on a corporate laptop with no partition.